# number of xml attributes->javascript multi array->function / process

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays

I have comments in a database relative to each post. It pulls the post and all comments according to that post in one query, and groups them inside an XML node. I get the amount of attributes in each node, and take away the standard number of attributes that every post has by default, and that leaves me with the number of comments.

The comment structure is as follows:

```
comment0           Hey nice post!
commentdate0       2014-12-1 08:25:02
commentaudthor0    Chris
comment1           cool!
commentdate1       2014-08-2 09:25:02
commentaudthor1    Jason
```

and so on, the comments increase by that number.

So I need to check how many comments there are (done) and then retrieve them from the xml node (using `$(this).attr('comment'+i)`) Where i would be the counter (`comment0, comment1` and so on)

Here is my current code to get it into the array:

```
var comms = new Array();
var count = this.attributes.length;
var av = count-11;
if(av != 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<av; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
            comms[i][j] = $(this).attr('comment'+i);
            comms[i][j+1] = $(this).attr('commentdate'+i);
            comms[i][j+2] = $(this).attr('commentauthor'+i);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

Now, how can I load it into a multi dimensional array to store the data, pass it to a function, and then process each row separately?

ie: this is what I am trying to do:

```
Array {
    'comment1':
        comment
        commentdate
        commentauthor
    'comment2':
        comment
        commentdate
        commentauthor
}
```

and then how would I be able to process each comment inside the function? ie: with each comment, do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really not a sensible use of XML attributes!

Comment: Why would you want to have comment1 and comment2 ??? just make an array and use this..

Comment: And why are you looping over `j`?

Comment: @lordkain I need to find a way to get all the comments displayed, and have no clue how to do this otherwise

Comment: @Eric I have no idea how to do it otherwise unfortunately

Comment: Use child elements for collections. Numbered attribute names feel pretty wrong to me.

Comment: @Eric Once this project is done, I will look into changing that. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the inner array before adding to it. Try this:

```
var comms = new Array();
var count = this.attributes.length;
var av = count-11;
//if(av != 0) { // I commented this condition out, as it is not needed here
    for(var i=0; i<av; i++) {
        comms[i] = []; // Create a new array here before adding to it (this syntax is more common than the longer "new Array()" syntax you used
        comms[i][0] = $(this).attr('comment'+i);
        comms[i][1] = $(this).attr('commentdate'+i);
        comms[i][2] = $(this).attr('commentauthor'+i);
    }
//}
```

Comment: I tried this, then I am passing the `comms` array into a function, but how do I 'decrypt' it within that function?

Comment: If your call is `myFunc(comms)`, then you can access it, e.g., a specific item, like `function myFunc (comms) {alert(comms[0][0]);}`. Note that you can rename `comms` in this second case. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking...

Comment: I have tried that, and it says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined `

Comment: Then you are either passing the "comms" array too early (e.g., within the loop) or, if after the loop, when it has not been populated... You really need to introspect the contents before sending them to the function to see what they contain and why they don't contain what you expect.

Comment: Your loop over `j` makes as much sense as the OP's (read: none)

Comment: Thanks @BrettZamir I logged it, I alerted it, and it turned out I couldn't use the word com as it was already used! rookie mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Eric: Good point; hadn't looked carefully at that. I have amended my answer accordingly.